# Adjust margins between math section and text

Tags: margins

How can one adjust the margin between a math environment (like align*) and the text that comes after?
E.g. I want the following look
[image]

but the default settings give me

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

map
\begin{equation*}
\Phi ( u) ( t) := u_{ 0}  + \int_{ t_{ 0} }^{ t} F( u( t') ) \, dt '.
\end{equation*}
Observe from (1.8) that a strong solution is nothing more

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you leave a blank line in the input between the preceding text and the code for the display?  That is often the cause of this extra space.

Comment: For a single equation you shouldn’t use `align*`, but rather `equation*`

Comment: @barbarabeeton It seems that the `align`environment adds this spacing\

Comment: @egreg ok thanks, you just wrote it in the same moment in that I recognised it.

Comment: @egreg still, the spacing is not as in the document I'm currently reading (for reference: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/chapter.pdf). Do you happen to know how one can adjust the margins?

Comment: Please, show code that produces the top picture.

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately I don't have access to it, the picture is taken from the pdf that I linked in the last comment.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant the *bottom* one, that is, the one you're producing.

Comment: @egreg I edited the post

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the wrong output if I don't leave a blank line before `\begin{equation*}`. If you don't have it, we need a more complete example.

Comment: @egreg so you get the same margin as in the first image? Because the code I compiled is a minimal example in that I only included the `amsmath` package (in the above images the margin between the math environment and the succeeding text differ by a factor of ~1.5 I would guess)

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure what you mean by “margins”: I guess “vertical space”. Are you using wider interline spacing, possibly with `setspace`?

Comment: @egreg no, the code above is all that is contained in my tex file

Comment: @egreg but I'm very certain that the vertical spacing in the first image is not the default vertical spacing, hence my question. E.g. rendering the same code in overleaf I also obtain the vertical spacing of the second image, so I'm just wondering how I can modify the default vertical spacing s.t. it looks like the first image.

Comment: @Richard: The first image may use adjusted spacing around math displays. For example, [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/SvcJVdKx) reduces the spacing around math displays by 50% ([output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30S7k.png)). You can adjust the factor to make things uniformly closer.

Comment: @Werner thanks a lot!